# Setting line height as multiplier in react native

Tags: react-native

In CSS line height can be set as follows

```
div {
    line-height: 20px; // absolute value
    line-height: 1.5; // multiplier
}
```

In native Android the same can be set as

```
<TextView
    lineSpacingMultiplier:'1.5'
    ...
```

How can the same be achieved in React Native. The docs dont have any information on line height multiplier. `lineHeight` property can be used to set absolute line heights only.

Any information on workarounds or how to custom add this functionality would be helpful.

**My text component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const line_height_multiplier = 1.5
const default_font_size = 13

export default TextNode = ({style={}, children}) => {
    return(
        <Text style={[styles.text_style, parent_style]}>{children}</Text>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text_style: {
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        fontSize: default_font_size,
        color: '#333',
        lineHeight: default_font_size * line_height_multiplier
    }
})
```

Here if `parent_style` contains a `fontSize` different than the **default fontSize 13**, how can I dynamically change the `lineHeight`. I am unable to access `parent_style.fontSize` to detect if it contains 'fontSize' (`parent_style` can be an object or an array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most examples I've come across usually define a `lineHeight` as a function of `fontSize` this way:

```
function lineHeight(fontSize) {
  const multiplier = (fontSize > 20) ? 1.5 : 1;
  return parseInt(fontSize + (fontSize * multiplier), 10);
}
```

You can fit whatever value for the multiplier.

The important formula here is that `lineHeight = fontSize + (fontSize * multiplier)`.

https://snack.expo.io/By_BJq_TW

Comment: I have a custom component which contains a `<Text>` element. So I would not know what the final fontSize would be on that. fontSize can be overridden by the parent. So the line height multiplier should dynamically change according to the final fontSize. How would that work out ?

Comment: Depending on your component hierarchy, you can access the styles passed down from the parent component. See https://snack.expo.io/r16QvqdT-

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks! Would be great if you could include `StyleSheet.flatten` technique in your answer. Would be helpful for others

Comment: @Anubhav I don't get how `StyleSheet.flatten` can get applied here, would you mind providing more details?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `borderBottomWidth` and be adjusting it till you get the height you want