# How to have in react-native lineHeight css style without px on mobile?

Tags: css, react-native

If I have `lineHeight:1.6` my browser and my android add `px` after it.
So the result is `1.6px`.

And if I add there quotation marks " or ' it will result into desired behavior in my browser.
But my mobile show error `Error while updating property 'lineHeight' in shadow node of type: RCTText`. And it means that I need to add number there, not string.

How can I make it work?

My code is running in expo:

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
    placeholdersText: {
        lineHeight: 1.6,
    },
});
```

```
import React from "react";
import {Text, View} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";

const Placeholders = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text
                    style={styles.placeholdersText}
                >
                    TEXT
                </Text>
            </View>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: I suppose you will have to check for [`Platform`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform#os), and based on which platform the app is running, use different `lineHeight` format.

Comment: You can look at this question [Multiplier in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861559/setting-line-height-as-multiplier-in-react-native). It could help you.